# How to add csrf_token to manually created HTML form?

Tags: django, django-forms, csrf, django-csrf

When creating a HTML form using Django format_html, I need to insert the `csrf_token` at the place of `{% csrf_token %}` below, since the use of `{% csrf_token %}` of course don't substitute when using `format_html`:

```
res = format_html('''
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {}
</form>''', ...
```

How do I manually generate the equivalent of `{% csrf_token %}` which is inserted when rendering a HTML template by Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution based on other SO post, and the method is to add a hidden field with `csrf_token` like:

```
res = format_html('''
<form method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{}" />
  {}
</form>''', csrf(html_request)['csrf_token'], ...)
```